# HTML Form with Submit Button, No Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a form:

```
<form id="inviteForm" action="">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="invite()">Invite</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

You can see that I have a submit button. I like that the submit button checks the form validity, but don't want to submit anything when it is pressed (this is all handled by the invite() js method).

**How can I continue to use the submit button as a form validator but not submit anything with it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
onclick="invite();"
```

Consider using:

```
onclick="return invite();"
```

or using:

```
onclick="invite(); return false;" // This will cease the form submission at any cost.
```

However, the first option will return the value of the return value of `invite()` function to the event listener. You can decide whether you wanna submit or not, using a simple check something like this:

```js
function go() {
  return document.getElementById("chk").checked;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.example.com/">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
  <input type="submit" value="Check to Go" onclick="return go();" />
</form>
```

Comment: @JannickeTvedt We know it's not you. Sorry, this is happening in your question. Do you think the answer works?

Comment: Worked!! But, the only way the worked was to "return invite();" and in invite() add return false. Doing "invite(); return false" did not submit it but also did not do the live form validation. Thanks so much!! Would help if you could upvote me as well as I think it is a valid quesiton.

Comment: @JannickeTvedt I have just given multiple ideas and suggestions. Even for the other one I have strongly given, it will never submit the form. Just other ways of thinking...  Glad it helped you.